# Load saved svg shapes and access them through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am trying to draw svg shapes, add events(click, drag etc.) and properties to the shapes and save them to server from my web application. I also want to load these saved shapes from the server and access their events and properties from my web application.

**My Problems are:**

**A.** I can not load a previously saved svg shape while I am drawing new ones at the same time. I am trying to load saved svg blocks by using `.html()`. I have tried using `append` also with same results.

In this **[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vb3jq/6/)** I have tried to create a similar scenario. Once you click Load Annotation Button, an svg block renders. But it erases the previous element.

**B.** Before loading the saved annotations, if you click the existing line, you will find that the element is being selected (alert message with the id of element). But after you add saved annotations to the svg block, you cannot find the elements by clicking on them.

there must be something I am doing wrong. Can you point it out please?

Comment: How about trying `d3.select("#SVGBlock").append("g").html("__your saved svg__")`.

Comment: Yes, That works. But still I cannot get the click event on that saved svg.

Comment: I'm still not sure how you are going to implement this, and with what data/saved svgs, but you can reference it and add the event listener using d3.
check out http://jsfiddle.net/Vb3jq/8/